# one subtle differs between C and C++

Tags: c

The following C statement is invalid in C++.

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
```

Why? How do you fix it?

The answer is :

> C performs an implicit conversion for
>   void *, while C++ does not. Use an
>   explicit cast to work around this.

My question is: explicit cast to whom and where?
thanks.

Comment: Why are you using malloc in C++ for this simple task anyway... :P. Answer is to explicitly cast the return of malloc to an int*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you have to say

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*a));
```

because casting a `void*` into an `int*` isn't implicitly done by the compiler.

Better yet, just use `new` and `delete`:

```
int *a = new int();
```

Comment: And if you must cast, use C++ casts.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: in this case that advice is misplaced -- the only reason to use a cast is if you use `malloc` instead of `new`. The *only* excuse for doing that is if you need to keep your code compatible with C -- which a C++ cast would obviously break. If you're going to make it specific to C++, eliminate the cast entirely.

Comment: @Jerry: "*only* excuse" is a bit over-stated ;-P.  Obvious example: performance implications of `realloc` may justify use of C-style libs (though profiling and not intuition should guide this).  Quite agree that interoperability's the main one, though it's not just "compatible with C", but with any code written in any language that will - for whatever reason - continue to use `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: if you'll excuse the pet peeve, "In C++ you have to say ... malloc(sizeof(*a));" - no you don't!  Like `return`, `sizeof` is not a function; the argument only needs to be parenthesised if it's a type, so "...malloc(sizeof *a);" is better (notwithstanding that some very old MS C++ compiler apparently choked on this).

Comment: @Tony: I did *not* know that o___o but I'm still not gonna use it. :P Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: @Tony: Well, okay, on *rare* occasion other reasons may apply.